# Indexing down multiple levels in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, iterable

I know this is probably a pretty basic one, but I've looked and I can't find the answer.

I have a system running trees (nested dict objects) that can be of arbitrary depth.

At present, a subtree index is stored as a list of keys, so in the structure:

```
example = { 1 : "foo" ,
            2 : { 2 : "bar" } ,
            3 : { 3 : { 3 : "zip" } } }
```

the index of "foo" is `[1]`, the index of "bar" is `[2,2]` and the index of "zip" is `[3,3,3]`.

At the moment, I'm iterating through the list with a for loop :

```
pointer = root_of_tree
for index in index_list :
  pointer = pointer[index]
```

This works pretty well, but it strikes me that Python is the sort of language that might have a built-in way of handling this case.

Is there a one-line solution? Perhaps a method of the iterable class?

Comment: You can use the same logic with list comprehensions `[pointer[index] for index in index_list]` and to get a list of all "pointers", Also i think it will be easier to change your indexing method instead of finding a better option for solving the current issue.

Comment: what exactly are you setting?